# Calculating how long a user spend in New form and editform.aspx

Tags: 2013

Business Requirements:
I require a way to track how long a ticket takes to complete (including time spent "working on" the ticket). Essentially I have a SP2013 list, which I can customise using InfoPath

My colleagues take a phone call and start a ticket by clicking new item. If they spend 20 mins on that phone call, then press save. Then go back into it and work on the ticket for 30 mins, then press save, then go back into the item and call the customer back and that takes 10 mins. I'd like to be able to see that the particular ticket took 1 hour to complete.

Questions As Follows:

1. Is this even possible in SP2013?
2. What would I need to do this? Workflows, JScript, Event Handlers etc
3. Considering my limited sharepoint experience (I'm not a developer) would I be able to google the answers?

Comment: Its possible , but you need to have a developer for this requirement. Nothing OOTB.

Answer (score 7):

I find your requirement interesting, as it is quite common for a ticketing system.

SharePoint can't do this natively, the reason being that the created and modified dates get written when an item is actually inserted and updated. You need to track the time spent on a form, that is the timespan between the click on the "add new item"/"edit item" button and the click on the "save" button.

The only thing I can see as feasible is resorting to some javascript to keep track of the time spent. So basically a timer function that kicks off as soon as the new form/edit form is opened and on saving, sets a hidden field value with the elapsed time (I would go for the total number of seconds elapsed, it should be easier working with the value later).

This is not that complicated, but some knowledge of both SharePoint and javascript is required.
The complete receipt is as follow:

- add a new column of time Number to your list. Call it eg. timespan
- in SharePoint designer: create a new "new form" and new "edit form" and set them as the default for your list.
- add a script tag to the body of each form, with the following javascript code:

--

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var startTime = Date.now();        
</script>
```

add a PreSaveAction function that will get called when the save button is clicked:

```
function PreSaveAction(){
    var endTime = Date.now();
    var elapsed = (endTime - startTime) / 1000;  // total number of seconds
    var timespanFieldValue = $('[title="timespan"]').val(); //current timespan (this should have some value if in edit form)
    var currentTimespan = isNaN(parseInt(timespanFieldValue )) ? 0 : parseInt(timespanFieldValue);
    $('[title="timespan"]').val(currentTimespan + elapsed);
}
```

(The last javascript snippet requires jQuery).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using SharePoint 2013 and in SharePoint 2013 Client-Side-Rendering (CSR) is a default rendering mode, below is demonstrated the `CSR` solution.

The solution consist of:

- Duration Text field  for storing the duration of time when
  the item was in Create/Edit Mode
- JavaScript Template file for calculating of duration in New/Edit Form pages, displaying
  duration in user friendly format (minutes) in Display Form and View pages

### Duration column

Assume the tickets are stored in `Tasks` list.
Let's add a Text column named `Duration` to track how long a ticket takes to complete into Tasks list.

### JavaScript template file

Key points:

- The value in `Duration` column is stored in Milliseconds ( see `durationEdit` function for a details)
- Since value in `Duration` column is stored in Milliseconds, function
  `formatDuration` is used to display formatted value (in minutes) for
  Display Form & View pages

File: `Tasks.js`

```
(function () {


    function durationEdit(renderCtx) {
       var fieldCtx = SPClientTemplates.Utility.GetFormContextForCurrentField(renderCtx);
       var durationControl = SPFieldText_Edit(renderCtx); 

       var startDate = new Date();
       var durationVal = renderCtx.CurrentFieldValue.length > 0 ? parseInt(renderCtx.CurrentFieldValue) : 0;


       fieldCtx.registerGetValueCallback(fieldCtx.fieldName, function(){
          var endDate = new Date(); 
          durationVal+= (endDate - startDate); 
          return durationVal.toString();
       });

       return durationControl;

    }


     function durationDisplay(renderCtx) {
        renderCtx.CurrentFieldValue = formatDuration(renderCtx.CurrentFieldValue); 
        return SPField_FormDisplay_Default(renderCtx);
     }

     function durationView(renderCtx) {

        return formatDuration(renderCtx.CurrentItem.Duration); 
     }

    //Format Duration column to display value in minutes
    function formatDuration(val)
    {
        if(val !== null  && val.length > 0) {
            return Math.round(((parseInt(val) % 86400000) % 3600000) / 60000) + ' min';
          }
        return '0 min';  
    }





    function registerRenderer()
    {
      var ctxTmpl = {};
      ctxTmpl.Templates = {};
      ctxTmpl.Templates.Fields = {
          'Duration' : { 'NewForm': durationEdit, 'EditForm': durationEdit, 'DisplayForm' : durationDisplay,'View' : durationView }
      };

      SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(ctxTmpl);
    } 
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(registerRenderer, 'clienttemplates.js');

})();
```

### How to apply changes

Set the [JSLink property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.basexsltlistwebpart.jslink.aspx) for a Web Part in `New Form (NewForm.aspx)`, `Edit Form (EditForm.aspx)`, `Display Form (DispForm.aspx)` and `View (AllItems.aspx)` pages.

Steps:

- Upload JavaScript template file into Site Assets library
- Edit the page, then edit the web part. Under Advanced specify
  JavaScript template file location in JS Link property: `~sitecollection/SiteAssets/Tasks.js`

### Results

Task Display Form page

[image]

Task View page

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this if your using infopath, but the time spent needs to be reported through excel. Use infopath IRules. So before they access the form they save only and then another submit at the end of the form. You can then use the created and midfield fields to show the time difference. You may need to format and validate to keep the form structure.