# Calculating how long a user spend in NewForm and EditForm using InfoPath Forms

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, jslink, infopath-2013

Based on this question:

[Calculating how long a user spend in New form and editform.aspx](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/94634/calculating-how-long-a-user-spend-in-new-form-and-editform-aspx)

I am having trouble adding the JSLink to the WebPart of the InfoPath Form.  When I go to Edit WebPart, the field for JSLink is not available.  I tried added the JS Link to "Script Editor", however, that does not work either.  I am using SP Online with InfoPath Form.

Can someone please guide me how to add a JSLink to a InfoPath Form? I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you,
Jeff

Comment: Can you clarify some points please? Would it be easier to customize the form using Power Apps? Also, what if you just insert either a Content Editor Webpart or a Script Editor webpart to the form? Did you have any issues doing this? if so, what are the issues exactly?

Comment: Hi @DenisMolodtsov, currently we are still using InfoPath Forms for a few more months. When I added the JS Link in either the Content Editor or Script Editor, it would so the URL/Link to the JS file.   I am thinking I must need something before and after the JSLink Url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using CEWP.

External file you reference by the CEWP must be an .HTML file. You can't reference .JS files. So, inside your external HTML file, add a `<script>...</script>` tag. Then, inside this script tag, add your JavaScript.

**Example of the TimeTracker.html file**

```
<script>
  alert('it works!') 
  // Add JavaScript that measures time
</script>
```